# $n (of a bison's rule) is returning the value of the previous token read

Tags: c, parsing, bison

I have the following bison's rule on my .y:

```
constant_definition: T_ID T_EQUAL T_INT_CONST T_SEMICOLON
{
    if(!insert_const($1, T_INTEGER))
    {
        printf("ERROR:... ");
    }       
};
```

my token's:

```
%token T_ID                   1
%token T_EQUAL                42
%token T_INT_CONST            2
%token T_SEMICOLON            33

...
```

my union:

```
%union
{
    int token1;
    int token2;
    int token_int_value;
    float token_float_value;
    int token_boolean_value;
}

%type<token2> T_ID 
%type<token_valor_real> T_REAL_CONST
%type<token_valor_int> T_INT_CONST
%type<token_valor_boolean> T_BOOLEAN_CONST
```

my yylex:

```
int yylex(void)
{
    token token_read = next_token();

    switch(token_read .token1)
    {
    case T_ID :
        yyval.token2 = token_read.token2;
        break;
    case T_INT_CONST:
        yyval.token_int_value = token_read.token_int_value;
        break;
    case T_REAL_CONST:
        yyval.token_float_value = token_read.token_float_value ;
        break;
    case T_BOOLEAN_CONST:
        yyval.token_boolean_value = token_read.token_boolean_value ;
        break;
    default:
        yylval.token1 = token_read.token1;
        break;
    }

    return token_read.token1;
}
```

Suppose I have the following sequence of token (token1) read:
5 1 33 39 **1(4) 42 2 33** 1(5) 42 2 33...

Ever time that bison's rule matches, $1 returns the previous token1's value instead of the secondary token related to T_ID.

For example:
This sequence "1 42 2 33" matches, but $1 is returning "39"

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't put a `;` at the end of your token sequence in `constant_definition:` -- put it at the end of the whole rule, after the final `}`.

Comment: Sure! Thanks. That was a typo mistake. I still have the same problem.

Comment: Maybe the error is in `next_token()`... also you didn't copied the sequence of `token2` parallel to that of `token1`.

Comment: I think my next_token() is correct. I tested it separately and, for this test case, the token1's sequence is correct and next_token() also return the correct token2 for a T_ID. I added the token2 to the sequence inside "(" and ")".

Comment: Half of the time you have `yyval` and the other half of the time you have `yylval`!  Is this another typo?  Please stop and post **the code you are using**.

Comment: How is token defined? If it's a union instead of a struct, you are accessing the same data with different names. eg you read token1 and token2 from the same data.

Comment: If you really did intend to have those `yyval`s be `yylval`s, then I notice that you never set `yylval.token1` for `T_ID` at all.  So if you are examining `$1.token1` in your Bison rule, it is uninitialized garbage.

Comment: Geez! That was the problem! I should have used yylval instead of yyval. Thank you guys!

Comment: This is the problem copying someone's code!

Comment: By default, Bison (and Yacc) reserve token ID numbers 0..257 and assigns token number 258 to the first token.  It is generally considered unwise to override that.  All else apart, if your lexical analyzer ever returned a character such as `*` (ASCII code 42), it would be interpreted as T_EQUAL, or `!` (ASCII code 33) would be interpreted as T_SEMICOLON.  It is just too dangerous.  You should review why you use user-assigned token values.  It should make no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the interest of having the answer be in an answer rather than being inside a comment (via @librik):

In `yylex`, the value being assigned to should be `yylval`, not `yyval`.

`yyval` stores the current value of the left hand side of a semantic action.
`yylval` stores the currently read token's value.

They're both the same type (YYSTYPE), so assigning wrongly doesn't raise an error.

When you don't set `yylval` in `yylex`, the value in yylval keeps the value read by the last token that had been set (in your case, the last token read that wasn't an T_INT_CONST/T_REAL_CONST/T_BOOL_CONST/T_ID). Hence, using yylval instead of yyval will fix it.